# Function callback does not execute

Tags: node.js, function, callback, routes, httpresponse

I have the following **signup route**, where after successful registering a **verification message** should be sent, which currently does not run.

Example : `mailer.sendEmail(res, req.body, token)`.

No errors in the console. It could be something wrong with the way I am passing the parameters.

Can anyone help?

**server.js**

```
app.post('/signup-user', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res) => {
    let sSignupUserImagePath = req.file.path.split("public/").pop()
    Object.defineProperty(global, "sSignupUserImagePath", {
        value: sSignupUserImagePath
    })
    let token = jwt.sign({
        username: req.body.email,
    }, 'supersecret', {
        expiresIn: 240
    });
    user.signupUser(req.body, (err) => {
        if (!err) {
            mailer.sendEmail(res, req.body, token)
        }
    })
})
```

**user.js**

```
var user = {}

user.signupUser = (jUserData, res) => {

    var aData = [
        null,
        jUserData.first_name,
        jUserData.last_name,
        jUserData.email,
        jUserData.mobile_number,
        sSignupUserImagePath,
        0
    ]
    var sQuery = 'INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'

    db.run(sQuery, aData, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('BAD, user not registered')
            return res(err)
        }
        console.log('GREAT, user registered')
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the res function you are passing to the function when you are executing them; if everything goes right you have to call:

```
db.run(sQuery, aData, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('BAD, user not registered')
        return res(err)
    }
    console.log('GREAT, user registered');
    res(null); //or also res(); works
});
```